# Setting size and position of file reader object on webpage

Tags: javascript

In my project, I allow users to select an image for their profile picture. Once the user selects this image, the selected image is displayed in the web browser. Here is the code for this.

**JS**:

```
 // profilePic is the id of the file input
    $("#profilePic").change(function(e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

            var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

            var img = document.createElement("img");
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                 img.src = reader.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            $("#profilePic").after(img);
        }
    });
```

This successfully works, and the image the user selects is displayed in the web browser. However how do I position the **selected image**, and set a size to it, so the position and size of the image is the same each time? What does the JS/CSS code look like for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You can use `.style.cssText` in order to add CSS to the created `<img>` tag.

```
// profilePic is the id of the file input
$("#profilePic").change(function(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

    var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

    var img = document.createElement("img");

    // add css to the image
    img.style.cssText = "height: 150px; width: 150px";

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      img.src = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    $("#profilePic").after(img);
  }
});
```

In addition, you can add any position you need inside this CSS function.

**2)** Or you can also add a class to it.

```
// profilePic is the id of the file input
$("#profilePic").change(function(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

    var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

    var img = document.createElement("img");

    // add class to the image
    img.classList.add("fixedImage");

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      img.src = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    $("#profilePic").after(img);
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.fixedImage {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Hello.I implemented your code, however I the image is not displayed in the browser at all. Instead `Uncaught TypeError: img.css is not a function` message is returned to the JS console. Do you know why?

Comment: Also, I have imported full jQuery package via a CDN, therefore that is definitely not the issue. The CDN is also imported before my own script tag where this code is implemented. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Edited. I forgot about selecting it using jQuery, but I used now plain JavaScript. Why do you think that call jQuery before your code is an issue? I mean, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Why would you use `.cssText` over, say, a class that is defined in a stylesheet?

Comment: Right. Added this option as well.